# Updating a DictField in MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongoengine

How can I add data to a dictionary in mongoengine?
I do not have the data to save the entire dict again, I only have one item I want to add at a time.

I have tried using:

```
Lookups.objects(pk="52d3a8e318fbaf0e1075de4f").update(push__schools=new_schools)
```

But I think the reason why this is not working is because `push` is to add an item to a list, not a dict. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use $set eg:

```
Lookups.objects(pk="52d3a8e318fbaf0e1075de4f").update(set__schools__KEY=VALUE)
```

**Updated:**

If you want to set multiple keys then you can eg:

```
Lookups.objects(pk=x).update(set__schools__KEY=VALUE, set__schools__KEY1=VALUE1)
```

Taking a dict of keys and values - you can convert to a new dict and update like so:

```
new_schools = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
set_new_schools = dict((("set__schools_%s" % k, v) for k,v in new_schools.iteritems()))
Lookups.objects(pk=x).update(**set_new_schools)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, say if instead of entering one at a time I want to add 2 entries, that is in a dict? how would I add that to the `DictField`? I have tried using `set` as well, but this replaced the entire field.

Comment: And How would I make `KEY` a different ? currently the word `KEY` is literally the Key that gets stored for each `VALUE`

Comment: Updated the answer :) But you would need to set each field

Comment: `set_new_schools = dict((("set__schools__%s" % k, v) for k,v in new_schools.items()))`
for python 3

Comment: I had forgotten about this. So I googled how to update a DictField, and found this again. XD. you gotta love stackoverflow!